# clang-format simple C format: dont space before variable and last return

Tags: c, clang-format

First declaraction variable and last return don't have a space.
How do I change my .clang-format for this options?

```
int main()
{
int a = 1;
char b;

 printf("declare variable without space\n");
 /* code */

return 1;
}
```

in default gnu i get ugly:

```
int main()
{
 int a = 1; /* how delete space before int */
 char b;

 printf("declare variable without space\n");

 return 1; /* how delete space before return? */
}
```

Comment: AFAICT, the options you want are not part of any widely-used formatting style. It may be difficult (or impossible) to find the exact options for clang-format. Maybe you can find something almost right, then pass your code through your own indenting program just for what's left.

Comment: @pmg that's sad

Comment: You might be able to do `IndentWidth: 0`. I only hope that you don't attempt to contribute to any open source code with this formatting...

Comment: @Locke It seems that OP wants to have no indent on variable initialization and some indent on the rest of the code.

Comment: @Locke I need IndentWidth 0 only for last return and only for declate variable in first declare. No in whole functions

Comment: @EliaszŁukasz And declarations done in the middle of the function, where should they be placed?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. Variable declarations as well as the word 'return' should be cut off as something that is not function action code but only declaration and return of values. Humans naturally read things with a space at the beginning first. In normal C not exist trouble declare after ;-)

Comment: I know everyone else in the comments is going to hate me for suggesting this, but... If everything is in `main` and you don't care about code style and conventions then why not just make them global variables. It is 4am and I'm in a bit of a *just let it all burn* sort of mood.

Comment: I think the first clarification we need is whether this is C or C++, and then if this is C89, which only allows variable declarations at the beginning of the scope. For C89 this might make some remote sense.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You are right (I edit topic spetialy for You comment)

Comment: @EliaszŁukasz Did you manage to get `clang-format` to do what you want? If you did, please consider writing an answer to help other people who might have the same question. If you didn't, please consider accepting the answer saying that it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I change my `.clang-format` for this options?

`clang-format` (up to at least version 10.0.1) does not support that formatting.

Comment: Apparently someone found a way to setup `clang-format` to do the formatting like OP wants since this answer just got downvoted. I'll happily delete this answer if someone proves me wrong.